# Send custom build info from Jenkins to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins

I am trying to send custom build information and post it to an index in elasticsearch. I have looked into the logstash plugin but that seems to be an overhead and has limitation.

I looked up the examples but there are no clear examples of how to map the date time and unique id when posting data to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the elastic documentation and google, was able to find an answer to this.

To answer this problem entirely, it has to be in two parts. Formatting the date is most important. Kibana by default considers everything to be in UTC, so if you want to ensure it picks up your timezone properly so you to adhere to this format. I customized mine from the list here [ElasticSearch Formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

- There needs to be an index template created which properly sets the format of the date (**very important**) using which kibana can build your index pattern

**Index template**

```
  PUT _template/jenkins
    {
        "index_patterns" : [
          "jenkins"
        ],
        "settings" : {
          "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : "1",
            "number_of_replicas" : "1"
          }
        },
        "mappings" : {
          "jenkins_status" : {
            "properties" : {
              "date" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
              },
              "cookbook_name" : {
                "type" : "text"
              },
              "cookbook_version" : {
                "type" : "text"
              },
              "chef_environment" : {
                "type" : "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

**Create a Jenkins Shared Library**

```
import java.util.TimeZone
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def writeToElastic(Map keyValues = [:], String index, String type){
    final String currentTime = currentTime()
    def data = readJSON text: '{}'
    data['@timestamp'] = currentTime
    keyValues.each{ k, v -> data[k as String] = v as String }
    def jsonString = JsonOutput.toJson(data)
    echo "Elastic data: ${jsonString}"
    writeJsonToElastic(jsonString, index, type)
}

def writeJsonToElastic(jsonString, String index, String type) {
  def elastic_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
  sh """
    curl -X PUT "http://<<ELASTIC_HOST>>:<<PORT>>/${index}/${type}/${elastic_id}?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '${jsonString}'
  """
}
// Timezone is key with Elastic, so make sure you are setting it up properly.
def currentTime() {
    def now = new Date()
    final String currentTime = now.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ", TimeZone.getTimeZone('NZ'))
    echo "currentTime : ${currentTime}"
    return currentTime
}
```

**Call this method from Jenkins pipeline**

Best to add this in the cleanup stage, this will make sure it pushes to elastic in any possible outcome.

```
cleanup {
    script {
        //  Push metrics to Elastic
//  You can append as many key/value pairs as required in your job
        def keyValues = [:]
        keyValues.put('job_name', "${JOB_NAME}")
        keyValues.put('build_number', "${BUILD_NUMBER}")
        keyValues.put('branch_name', "${params.branch_name}")
        elastic.writeToElastic(keyValues, 'jenkins_jobs', 'jenkins_status')

        echo 'Cleaning up workspace'
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```